# RoR: CI and staging server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, continuous-integration, staging, cruisecontrol.rb

for our Ruby on Rails project, we want to use CruiseControl.rb for CI and we want to have a staging server. I don't have any experience with CruiseControl, so maybe someone can answer some of the questions below:

- Is it possible to use CruiseControl for integration tests with Cucumber or Steak with a headless browser like webkit or even Selenium?
- Is it possible to integrate JavaScript tests with Jasmin oder QUnit in CruiseControl?
- Is it possible to use RVM with CruiseControl?
- Is it possible to test a deployment with capistrano? And can this deployment used for staging?
- Is it possible to add post build processes, like copy the production database to the staging database?

If some of the requirements aren't possible, are there any other CI servers you can recommend?

thx a lot,

tux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do everything you want with CruiseControl or Jenkins or any other CI server. It doesn't really matter because, for example, running Selenium on headless server can be solved with `headless` gem and `Xvfb`.

You can do everything with just a nice build shell script.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I want to use CC.rb with Apache and Passenger, and also test capistrano deployments. But I can't find any good (and up-to-date) tutorials. Maybe you could give me some links where I can start using CC.rb with a Rails 3.2 app.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to go with a hosted continuous integration service like [Tddium](https://www.tddium.com) (disclaimer: I'm one of the founders).  It handles webkit and selenium setup, runs tests in parallel automatically, and can run custom post-build tasks, including running a capistrano deploy.